# How to make the MudDrawer takes up the 100% height

Tags: c#, mudblazor

I have a MudDrawer in my blazor application and i would like the MudDrawer to take up **entire height** of the page. Here is what i have tried :

```
    <MudDrawerContainer Class="mud-height-full">
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="@open" Width="300px" Height="900px" Fixed="true" Elevation="24" Variant="@DrawerVariant.Temporary" DisableOverlay="true" Style="background-color:aliceblue" Anchor="Anchor.End">
        <MudDrawerHeader>
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">My App</MudText>
        </MudDrawerHeader>
        <MudNavMenu>
            <MudNavLink Match="NavLinkMatch.All" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Store">Store</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Match="NavLinkMatch.All" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.LocalLibrary">Library</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Match="NavLinkMatch.All" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Forum">Community</MudNavLink>
        </MudNavMenu>
    </MudDrawer>

</MudDrawerContainer>
<div class="d-flex justify-center align-center mud-height-full">
    <MudButton Color="Color.Inherit" OnClick="@ToggleDrawer"
               StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.West" Class="mx-2">Toggle drawer</MudButton>
</div>


@code {
    bool open = false;


    void ToggleDrawer()
    {
        open = !open;
    }
}
```

As you can see i have set the Height to 900px but i want to be the height of the page i tried the 100% but i did not get the results i want. Here is the [demo](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GOmROykeSfhwOQAV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to stay in place and take up full height of the window/container then, you can add `positon:fixed;`

You can move it around using positional css i.e. top/bottom etc. I've added `top:40px` in the example just to show this.

[mudblazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mEGxESuTrfMdHnmp)

```
<MudDrawer @bind-Open="@open" Width="300px" Fixed="true" Elevation="24"
 Variant="@DrawerVariant.Temporary" DisableOverlay="true"
 Style="background-color:aliceblue;position:fixed;top:40px;" Anchor="Anchor.End">
    //..
</MudDrawer>
```